# Better way to add comma separated value to a datatable column when adding a new row in datatable

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop, datatable

I am adding **new row in datatable** in which i want to add comma separated value in **1 datatable column**.

This is how i am doing:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

var data=Helper.GetData();

 foreach (DataRow dr in data)
 {
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
      var append = new StringBuilder();
      var columns=Helper.GetColumns();

      char[] characters = new char[] { ' ', ',' };
      foreach(var item in columns)
      {
          if (columns.Count()==1)
          {
               dr["Id"] = dr[item].ToString();
               dr["Col1"] = dr[item].ToString();
          }
          else
          {
               dr["Id"] = dr[item].ToString();
               append.Append(dr[item].ToString() + ", ");
          }
      }
      if (columns.Count() > 1)
      {
          dr["Col1"] = append.ToString().TrimEnd(characters);//remove comma from the end
      }    
 }
```

Is there any better way to do this???

Comment: In what way _better_? What is the problem with your approach? If there is none this is off-topic for stackoverflow. Maybe you could ask this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TimSchmelter:I think i have written little more code like used string builder(i dont think which is needed),checking same conditions 2 times.Just a thought i might be wrong

Comment: No. Put it all together using StringBuilder and add it to the cell as String, like what you have done.

Comment: (1) What is `columns` and why they are retrieved inside the loop? (2) What should go to `Id` column and what to `Col1`? Currently you are setting `Id` with the value of each column inside the inner loop, so when you have multiple columns, the `Id` will contain the last column value, and `Col1` will contain the concatenation of all column values. Is this how it's supposed to be?

Comment: @IvanStoev:I will have 1 or more columns and so i want to loop through this column name and append all this column values to my Col1 column as comma seperated

Comment: @Learning That's the simple part that can be done easily with `string.Join`. Again, it's not clear what goes to `Id` column.

Comment: @IvanStoev:I have tried with string.join but problem was it was storing only last value and both Col Id will have same value as Col1 but Id will not be comma seperated

Comment: Hmm, what's the problem with `string.Join(", ", columns.Select(c => dr[c].ToString()))`?

Comment: @IvanStoev:I am not using linq thats because i have some logics in the loop that i why i am looping on columns otherwise i would definetely have used linq and apart from that then how i would assign 1 by 1 value to my Id column then??

Comment: @Learning You should include such information in the question. Looking at the code is absolutely unclear what are you doing and why. What about your `Id` column, I asked you two times and you didn't answer what is supposed to be put there.

Comment: @IvanStoev:But i said that Id will contains single values and Col1 will contains Comma seperated values like for eg:1,2,3,4 ( for 1 row)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115850/discussion-between-ivan-stoev-and-learning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your individual column values into a list and then concatenate them with [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var dt = new DataTable();

var data=Helper.GetData();

 foreach (DataRow dr in data)
 {
      List<string> values = new List<string>();
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

      var columns=Helper.GetColumns();

      foreach(var item in columns)
      {
          dr["Id"] = dr[item].ToString();
          values.Add(dr[item].ToString());
      }
      dr["Col1"] = string.Join(",", values);
 }
```

I admit to being a little confused about why you overwrite the "Id" column, but the code above should have the same effect as what you originally posted.

Comment: Can we do this without  taking any extra object??

Comment: @Learning: What do you mean "extra object?" If you're asking whether you can do this without the intermediate list, the answer is "no." But then, your method uses an extra object, too: the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: actually i wanted to get rid of using string builder that is why i have asked question here but anyways thank you so much for the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.it really helped me.Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you want right, here is a sample that depicts a simpler way:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("SO Example");

dt.Columns.Add("A", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("D", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Concatenation", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add(1, "bbbbbb", "tra la la", "d");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "b b b", "tttt", "dddddd");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "b-b-b-b-b-b", "C", "d.d.d.d.d.d");
dt.Rows.Add(4, "bBbBbBb", "CCC", "dd");
dt.Rows.Add(5, "B", "C", "D");

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["Concatenation"] = string.Join(", ", row.ItemArray.Take(row.ItemArray.Length - 1));
}
```

The table:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Create 1 column i.e F and try to add column value B and C in column F as comma seperated in datatable or just you can do this in column D with adding Column B and C as comma sperated in column D

Comment: do you know beforehand how many columns your datatable must have ? or you decide dynamically when to add a new column containing some of the current row fields concatenated ?

Comment: I have modified the code, adding a "Concatenation" column (last one) to the database to hold the concatenation for each row.

Comment: My question was to add comma seperated values in datatable column and currently you can consider taking fix columns

Comment: So I think the snippet above now does what you want, does it not ? I added a small fix to not concatenate the "Concatenation" field as well into the result (I take only all the previous columns).

Comment: Can you tell me something about this:row.ItemArray.Take(row.ItemArray.Length - 1));

Comment: `Take` is an IEnumerable extension method that references the first N parameter elements from the collection, while discarding the remaining items. Each `DataRow` object has an `ItemArray` property, which holds all its fields/cells. For the example above, where I thought of having a concatenation column with all the current row's fields - except the concatenation field itself - concatenated - I then do `row.ItemArray.Take`(the number of item array elements - 1 (the concatenation column , which is the last one).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.it really helped me.Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Veverke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077321/3762855) answer indicates the absolute best solution for you.
I just right tried to assemble your code integrating his solution...

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var data=Helper.GetData();
foreach (DataRow drSrc in data) //changed from "dr" in "drSrc" to readability (further, compiler should rises a syntax error)
{
   DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

   dr["id"] = drSrc[drSrc.ItemArray.Length - 2]; //the last value of drSrc (after clarifications in comments and chat..)
   dr["Col1"]  = string.Join(", ", drSrc.ItemArray.Take (drSrc.ItemArray.Length - 1));

   dt.Rows.Add(dr);  //it missed in your code, but I suppose you want add it into the datatable 
}
```

Comment: What if you dont know about the column position i.e you only know the column name with the datatable column creating dynamically then??

Comment: from your code I supposed that you were done some error on re-assigning id on each step of columns cycle, so I thought that the common solution of indexing the id column with 0 were quite good in this case. But if you intend iomplement sole dynamic mechanism of comopising datatable you have to map origin datasource with your destination datasource. I can suggest one method in an update section of the upon answer.

Comment: what method do you suggest??

Comment: sorry Learning, but seeing a bit better your code, I suspect that maybe I've done some little misunderstanding :) .. anyway, let's make some little clarifications.. you need to build at each cycle step of your origin data source, the columns that compose it?

Comment: i want to store comma seperated values in my Col1 column based on the number of columns

Comment: ok, let's say that your destination datatable has only 2 columns: ID and Col1, and you want store in ID col, the last column name of the datarow you are parsing in each cycle step, and in the Col1 the concatenation of all columns.. (maybe it is better to go on chat...)